# IIS : Is there a way to lock a file for update

Tags: file, iis, locking

My webiste uses IIS 7. It reads-updates-writes a file using System.IO.TextWriter.
Is there a way to lock the file during the read-update-write activity to prevent another process doing the same thing simultaneously. The second process shoud queue while the lock is active.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ReaderWriterLockSlim class to set a lock that is used to manage access to a resource, allowing multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing.

```
    public class Demo {
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _readWriteLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void WriteToFileThreadSafe(string text, string path) {
        // Set Status to Locked
        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // Append text to the file
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(text);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release lock
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0